# comprobar si existe sesión en login

Tags: php

Quiero que mi login verifique si existe una sesión o sino me permita iniciar sesion
este es mi codigo que agregue dentro de login:

```
<?php

session_start();
if($_SESSION['type'] == 1){
    //en caso de que se detecte un inicio de sesión usuario se redireccionará al menú del sistema
    header("location: views/user/index.php");
}
if($_SESSION['type'] == 2){
    //en caso de que se detecte un inicio de sesión administrador se redireccionará al menú del sistema
    header("location: views/admin/index.php");
}
```

al cargar el login sin la sesion iniciada me manda el mensaje

```
Notice: Undefined index: type in C:\xampp\htdocs\videos\consulta.php on line 46

Notice: Undefined index: type in C:\xampp\htdocs\videos\consulta.php on line 50
```

pero si tengo sesión iniciada me dirige bien a las vistas de cada usuario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según confirmas en los comentarios de esta respuesta quieres algo así:

```php
<?php

session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['type'])) {
    if($_SESSION['type'] == 1){
        //en caso de que se detecte un inicio de sesión usuario se redireccionará al menú del sistema
        header("location: views/user/index.php");
    }
    if($_SESSION['type'] == 2){
        //en caso de que se detecte un inicio de sesión administrador se redireccionará al menú del sistema
        header("location: views/admin/index.php");
    }
    die("Error inesperado. Tiene un tipo de sesión distinto al esperado. Contactar con el administrador del sitio.");
}
```

Es decir, con el condicional se verifica si existe la clave `type` dentro de la variable $_SESSION, que compruebo con la función [isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php), y en caso verdadero se procede con el resto de verificaciones.  En caso contrario no sucede nada y se esquiva el error, tal como quiere el OP.

Comment: Algo así hice para las paginas luego de iniciar sesion, pero quiero hacer algo parecido en el login en caso de que la sesion siga abierta el login dirija al usuario a su vista especifica y sino que le permita iniciar sesion

Comment: Pues si el error que aparece en tu pregunta te pasa con un usuario que ya ha iniciado la sesión entonces el problema es otro. Quizas el usuario a perdido la variable de sesión por su caducidad (en algunos servidores por defecto son 1400 segundos, que no es mucho) y por eso no reconoce la variable de sesión $_SESSION.  Tu error dice esto: `Notice: Undefined index: type ` y eso solo ocurre cuando no existe esa clave en la variable (o bien la variable completa quizas no existe, como decia). Revisa eso más bien. Asegurate que el usuario sigue logeado y que se le ha asignado esa clave bien.

Comment: ese error me lo manda antes de iniciar sesion, ya cuando la inicia todo funciona y si me regreso al login me manda a la ruta pero si cierro la sesion dejan de existir las variables de sesion y me manda el error de esa variable porque ya no existe

Comment: Así tengo mi código se sesión en el login https://ibb.co/Ryn4Z6K

Comment: En esta vista aun no hay sesion iniciada https://ibb.co/kytZvLp . pero si inicio sesion me funciona lo que hice

Comment: Vale, entonces lo quieres al reves. Revisa mi respuesta, que acabo de editar, a ver si así te vale. De este modo te saltas el error en tu página de login, pero piensa que en ese caso no hay ninguna variable $_SESSION con esa clave `type` definida, pero parece que lo quieres asi.

Comment: Ya funciono, muchas gracias por apoyarme

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro, saludos!